# Undefined output when using "reduce" to multiply an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, reduce

When multiplying an array of numbers like so I get the expected output:

```
 const numbers = [2, 5, 3];
 return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
```

However, when I originally wrote my reduce statement (as shown below) I got the output "undefined". I think this is to do with the value 0 I'm seeding the reduce with.

```
return numbers.reduce((a, b) => {
      a * b;
    }, 0);
```

I don't fully understand what is happening for "undefined" to be the output. If anyone could enlighten me on this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: In the second example you need an explicit `return`: `return a * b` because it's within a curly brackets statement.

Comment: I get 0 as the output when I put a return there.

Comment: Well, what is 0 times anything?

Comment: Ok changed to 1.

Comment: 0 is the initial value here, thus as Andy points out, you are multiplying everything by 0.

Answer (score 2):

In the second form you are using curly-braces `{}` in your arrow function, which has no implicit `return`.  If using curly braces you need to *explicitly* `return`:

```js
const numbers = [2, 5, 3];

const test = numbers.reduce((a, b) => {
   return a * b;
}, 0);

console.log(test);
```

**EDIT**

As has been pointed out in various comments, this fixes the issue of the result being `undefined`, but it will still be `0` because you are seeding the initial value as `0`, and `0` times anything is `0`.  You can simply omit this (or replace it with `1`) to get the product of all the items in the array returned:

```js
const numbers = [2, 5, 3];

const test = numbers.reduce((a, b) => {
   return a * b;
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the 0 to 1 since any number times 0 is 0:

```js
return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the purpose of providing the seeded value?

Comment: @Volper you can leave the initial value off: ["If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). This is why the OP's first example works.

Comment: @Andy oh, I didn't know that; but if you want the second example to work, add return like Alexander Nied said in his answer and remove the 0 or change it to 1